# gcc confused about what's an lvalue?

Tags: c, gcc, standards, lvalue

gcc is giving me invalid lvalue in assignment errors for:

```
-2[(size_t *)new] = 0;
```

Changing the code to the following makes it go away:

```
((size_t *)new)[-2] = 0;
```

but as far as I can tell, both are 100% equivalent in C. gcc has no problem using the former in non-lvalue expressions. Is this just a bug in gcc? I've tested it with several versions and got the same results.

Comment: everytime I think I know C, I see stuff like this and go "wtf?"

Comment: I knew that it is possible to access arrays like that but I never knew somebody actually does it like that...

Comment: @SB: No, this is a legitimate WTF.

Comment: Umm, maybe I'm missing something but why would you want to use the first expression over the second?

Comment: @Arkku: I don't understand why someone would use any of them.. and why call the variable `new`? Is it for delphi strings?

Comment: @ruslik: In the rare cases I use it, the goal is to reduce the level of parentheses (substituting `[]` which are visually distinct), but to correct the error here I'd have to add more adjacent parentheses which would probably hurt readability just as much.

Comment: @ruslik: I agree. Calling the variable `new` is just adding to the confusion. Especially to those that have done _any_ c++. (and because the syntax highlighting on this site highlights it as a keyword!)

Comment: Does anyone else feel that this question was probably just posted to earn more rep? That the poster knew the answer already? It usually takes me about 4 minutes to post an answer, so that leaves precious little time to suddenly realise the answer given that posting the question and posting the answer are only 4 minutes apart.

Comment: @AlastairG: feel free to downvote if you think that. I'm not sure what use there is in having more than 10k rep anyway unless you want to post lots of bounties and still keep your rep-based privileges...?

Comment: @AlastairG: Just look how many points @R. donated by downvoting others. So I don't think they means much for him. Also, it's quite a common practice to post articles in this way.

Comment: @ltn100: using "new" as a variable could be an ingenious way to ensure that C code is actually compiled with a C compiler, not a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Steve: there are standard ways to ensure that, and not code like `int new(int delete, int class){`. And after all, why should someone want that?

Comment: @ruslik: I was mostly joking, but the reason not to want that is that when writing C code, you might not think to ensure that it has the same semantics (for example that behavior is defined) when read as C++ that it does when read as C. I don't want my C code compiled as C++ for the same reason I don't want my `bash` scripts run under `ksh`. Lots of things will work. Some things won't, and I want to emphasise that this is the fault of the muppet who used the wrong compiler/interpreter. An immediate error beats subtly different behavior. But sure, from C99 you can just check `__cplusplus`.

Comment: I use the variable names `old` and `new` when they make sense in a function that's consuming an old object and replacing it with a new one (or in this case, splitting off a new object from an existing object). I'm not going to avoid using the obvious name for a variable just because it happens to be a keyword in a different language.

Comment: @ruslik: I have *zero* sympathy for C++ coders objecting to the use of `new` as a variable name.  It's a different language, get over it.  I promise not to complain if you use the keywords of some other language in your C++ code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm stupid. `[]` binds more tightly than `-`, so this expression is actually reading index 2 and negating it.

Comment: Is you being stupid, "an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet"?

Comment: Hm? I didn't delete the question because (1) I thought I deserved the shame of screwing this up, and (2) the answer is potentially interesting and a good reason why the construct I was using probably should not be used (in the few cases where I do use it, the intent is to reduce the levels of parentheses because I have visual/perceptual problems reading expressions with too many levels of parentheses).

Comment: Although I would never recommend using `index[ptr]` in production code, I understand your reasoning for doing so, and frankly I have to admire anyone who isn't ashamed of taking full advantage of C's general weirdness.  This is actually a very interesting lesson in operator precedence.

Comment: just wondering whether it should be closed. I accept your reason not to :-)